# Changing the number index of a series of files

Tags: loops, rename

I have 456 files in my linux account on a shared computer named like this:

ABC_0, ABC_1, ..., ABC_455

I want to add 911 to their index and rename them to

ABC_911, ABC_912, ..., ABC_1356

I have done this once before but I cannot find the script I used for it.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Which platform? which language?

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't really the *best* way to go about it, but it will work in a pinch:

```
import os, sys

def main():
    oldname_prefix = raw_input('Input old name prefix: ')
    starting_index = raw_input('Input starting index: ')
    ending_index = raw_input('Input the ending index (the size of the largest current file): ')
    file_format = raw_input('Input file format: ')
    new_starting_index = raw_input('Input the starting index of the new file names: ')
    i = int(starting_index)
    end = int(ending_index)
    difference = int(new_starting_index) - i
    while i <= end:
        old_name = oldname_prefix + str(i) + file_format
        new_name = oldname_prefix + str(i + difference) + file_format
        os.rename(old_name, new_name)
        i += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Create that, save it as "renaming.py" or something and put it in the same directory as the files you want to rename. Then type at the command line `python renaming.py`. When it prompts you, enter "ABC_", then "0", then "455", then whatever file format they are (if any, if not, just hit enter without typing anything), then "900" For example, if they are .txt files, it would look like this:

```
Input old name prefix: ABC_
Input starting index: 0
Input the ending index (the size of the largest current file): 455
Input file format: .txt
Input the starting index of the new file names: 900
```

To be doubly safe, I would suggest copying a small subset of your files to another location first and try it on those, just in case something doesn't work properly, but it's working fine for me.

---

Here's an alternative possibility, using only Bash.

```
user@computer:~/directory$ a=0
user@computer:~/directory$ b=900
user@computer:~/directory$ for i in ABC_*; do old=$(printf "ABC_%1d" "$a"); new=$(printf "ABC_%1d" "$b"); mv -- "$old" "$new"; let a=a+1; let b=b+1; done
```

First make sure you set `a` to the start value of the files now, and `b` is the start value of the files at the end. Then this function loops over each of the files of the format "ABC_*" in the current directory, grabs its current name, grabs its desired name, and then renames it. If the files have a file extension, in **both** of the `printf "ABC_%1d"` bits, change it to `printf "ABC_%1d.jpg", or whatever the extension is.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But is there any way based on linux command itself instead of writing a code.

Comment: it worked!Thanks a lot. I like the second one based on Bash